# Redirect www.example.com to example.com

Tags: .htaccess

I've a domain hosted on bluehost with iLister CMS installed in, the problem which I'm facing is http://www.advett.com/admin isn't responding because I registered advett.com/admin in the site_url field of iLister license.
How to redirect all the request for www.advett.com and www.advett.com/admin to advett.com and advett.com/admin respectively?
I know it can be done with .htaccess but I've not been able to find a solution till now.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.advett\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://advett.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks www.advett.com is redirecting to advett.com but www.advett.com/admin or advett.com/admin is redirecting to advett.com itself.
I want it to redirect to advett.com/admin only.

Comment: @JayPrakashSarma When I put those rules in a blank htaccess file and request `http://www.advett.com/admin` in apache, I get redirected to `http://advett.com/admin`. There's something else in your setup that's doing that.

Comment: it works for me. Jon, how would this be done if I needed http and https both to work?